# Is there a workaround to allow using a computed column in its own formula

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, calculated-columns

I have a column in my table called Value1. I then have a computed column, Value2, with the formula of;

```
(CASE WHEN [Value1] > [Value2] THEN [Value1] ELSE [Value2] END)
```

I can't save this as SQL Server balks at the self-reference of the Value2 computed column in the formula.

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Recursion makes my head spin. If you enter Value1 = 5, how is Value2 ever going to be anything other than 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you need to keep track of not only what value1 is now but also what value1 used to be. You won't be able to do that with a computed column, because it can only react to the current value, not itself or the previous value.

I suggest an [`INSTEAD OF TRIGGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288%28SQL.90%29.aspx) as opposed to a computed column. Here is a simple example:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.SparkyMark
(
    [key]    INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [string] VARCHAR(32),
    Value1   INT,
    Value2   INT
);
GO
```

An `INSTEAD OF INSERT TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SparkyMark_BeforeInsert
ON dbo.SparkyMark
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT dbo.SparkyMark([string], Value1, Value2)
        SELECT [string], Value1, Value1 FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

An `INSTEAD OF UPDATE TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SparkyMark_BeforeUpdate
ON dbo.SparkyMark
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE sm
        SET [string] = i.[string],
            Value1 = i.Value1, 
            Value2 = CASE WHEN sm.Value2 < i.Value1 THEN i.Value1 ELSE sm.Value2 END
        FROM
            dbo.SparkyMark AS sm
        INNER JOIN
            inserted AS i
            ON sm.[key] = i.[key];
END
GO
```

Now let's insert a couple of rows and prove we can maintain Value2 without ever inserting or updating that column directly:

```
INSERT dbo.SparkyMark([string], Value1) SELECT 'foo', 3;
INSERT dbo.SparkyMark([string], Value1) SELECT 'foo', 5;

-- Value1 and Value2 are the same:
SELECT * FROM dbo.SparkyMark ORDER BY [key];

-- they will still be the same because the new Value1 > old Value2:
UPDATE dbo.SparkyMark SET Value1 = Value1 + 1;
SELECT * FROM dbo.SparkyMark ORDER BY [key];

-- now they will be one less because the new Value1 < old Value2:
UPDATE dbo.SparkyMark SET Value1 = Value1 - 1;
SELECT * FROM dbo.SparkyMark ORDER BY [key];

-- in row 1 Value1 drops by 2 but Value2 stays the same:
UPDATE dbo.SparkyMark SET Value1 = Value1 - 2 WHERE [key] = 1;
SELECT * FROM dbo.SparkyMark ORDER BY [key];

-- and finally we get both values in both rows equal again:
UPDATE dbo.SparkyMark SET Value1 = Value1 + 5;
SELECT * FROM dbo.SparkyMark ORDER BY [key];
```

Clean-up:

```
DROP TRIGGER dbo.SparkyMark_BeforeInsert, dbo.SparkyMark_BeforeUpdate;
DROP TABLE dbo.SparkyMark;
GO
```

Comment: Just make sure the trigger can handle muliple row inserts/updates

Answer (score 2):

Computed columns will only compute when the record is SELECTED (for non-PERSISTED) or when some field the computation depends on is changed (for PERSISTED).

So one way you could serve the same function (without a trigger) would be to re-work your stored procedure a little.  An update might go like this...

```
ECLARE @myVar varchar(max)
UPDATE dbo.myTable
SET [value1] = 3,
    [value2] = CASE WHEN [value2] < 3 THEN 3 ELSE [value2] END
WHERE ...
```

It's not as automatic as you might have with a trigger, but if you can avoid those -- they're often a little too much like work, when it comes to mod-ing your table, maintenance, upgrades, etc.  And you have to make sure they can fail gracefully, just in case.

Comment: I suggested an instead of trigger not because I thought it would be fun to do more work, but because I assumed based on the question that he could have just updated the stored procedure to perform the case if it were that simple. My guess is that for data modification there is/are (a) no stored procedures, (b) many stored procedures, or (c) a mix of ad-hoc and stored procedures.

Comment: @Aaron -- I realize that, and actually I would tend to make the same assumption you did.  But to avoid unnecessary pain and suffering :-P, I'd always want to make sure there weren't feasible alternatives first.  Sometimes triggers are the right answer, I know.  It was a good answer you gave.